# Make pandas raise on divide by zero instead of inf

Tags: pandas

I would like to have pandas raise an exception when dividing by zero as in:

```
d = {'col1': [2., 0.], 'col2': [4., 0.]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
2/df
```

Instead of the current result:

```
0    1.000000
1         inf
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Any suggestions how to achieve that?

I know with numpy I can `np.seterr(divide='raise')` but pandas does ignore that.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't know how pandas raises an exception for divide by zero. But at least you can use `try:
    buffer = 2/df.values
    new_df = 2/df
except Exception as e:
    print("Zero")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closer look into the source code and the trace shows that inside `pandas` you can find a lot of context handlers like this:

`with np.errstate(all='ignore'):`

or

`with numeric.errstate(all='ignore'):`

This is the reason why `np.seterr` is ignored and there is probably no easy way to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

It's far from ideal, but one potential option is to interpret the elements of your dataframe as Python objects rather than the more optimized `numpy` or `pandas` dtypes that it typically uses:

```
In [37]: d = {'col1': [2., 0.], 'col2': [4., 0.]}
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    ...: 2/df

Out[37]:
   col1  col2
0   1.0   0.5
1   inf   inf

In [38]: 2 / df.astype('O')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```